# c++ typeid operator

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, compiler-construction

I am using Visual Studio 2005 Proffesional Edition.

In the following example SomeClass is class that is defined in third party dll library I am using.
SomeClass has virtual methods. I noticed that the operator typeid gives different results when applied to the type itself, and when applied to object of the type. Is this normal behavior, and if not what could be the reason for such behavior?

```
typeid(SomeClass).raw_name()   // the value of this is   ".?AVSomeClass@@"
typeid(SomeClass).name()          ///  "class SomeClass"

SomeClass obj;
typeid(obj).raw_name(); // ".?AVTLomeClass@@"
typeid(obj).name();       // "class TLomeClass"
```

Comment: 0% aspect rate.  Not going to answer this.  Especially after I found out that I already anserred one of your questions. :-)

Comment: The questions i looked into were solved - to accept the most helpful answer to your questions use the check mark.

Comment: @unknown: Is the the real code you are having problems with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the code in your question the same or similar to the code you are having problems with?

Operator `typeid`, when it is applied to polymorphic types, returns the `type_info` object that identifies the *dynamic* type of the polymorphic object. So, for example, if you apply `typeid` to a reference of type `Base &` (where `Base` is polymorphic), which is actually bound to an object of type `Derived` (where `Derived` is derived from `Base`), the `type_info` object returned by `typeid` will correspond to the `Derived` class, not to `Base` class. Could it be that something like that is happening in your code?

Also, in some compilers (like MS Visual Studio) in order to use fully-functional `typeid`, as described above, you need to compile your code with Run-Time Type Information (RTTI) enabled. Maybe the absence of RTTI led to the strange effects you observed.

P.S. Contrary to what is stated in the currently accepted answer, `typeid` is fully and perfectly standard C++ feature. It is not a compiler extension.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In my example I was having a library function that returns base pointer which  points to derived class object. However, the signature of the function was Base* function(), and in the library documentation Base class apperead as leaf class i.e no classes were specified to inherit from it. But I guess so, that the function actually was returning a pointer which points to more derived class which is not sayed in the libary documentation. I.e if I say this :
Base baseObj;
Base* basePtr=fucntion();
then the following statement is true
typeof(baseObj)!=typeof(*basePtr)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behavior is documented somewhere [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyf39xec%28VS.80%29.aspx). The specific behavior you're seeing in this particular case is probably due to some use of inheritance, or some compiler extension, not documented by the .DLL's vendor.

The operator's behavior is not defined by the C++ standard, and as such is a compiler extension. You can not rely on its behavior, nor can you have any reasonable expectation of finding out why it does what it does in the way that it does, unless it's explicitly documented by the vendor. Its behavior may have changed in VS2008, and likely differs from VS2003. (It certainly differs from GCC, ICC, and various other compilers.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.This help me a lot. Actually, after some investigation, I came to conclusion that the vendor has some undocumented futures of the particular class.

Comment: I'm sorry: what?!!! Operator `typeid` is clearly and explicitly defined by C++ standard. It is not a compiler extension.

Comment: Yes, typeid is 8defined* in the standard, but its *behavior* is not. The only explicit requirement is that: `typename A a1, a2; assert(typeof(a1) == typeof(a2));` Anything beyond that, by my reading, is an extension.

Comment: No, the behavior of `typeid` is perfectly defined, at least for the purposes it is intended to be used for. There's nothing undefined in type-identification properties of `typeid`. In case of `A a;` the standard guarantees that `typeid(A) == typeid(a)`. What is really undefined, is the format of the "names" returned by the above methods, but that's not the issue in this case.

Comment: The operators behaviour is well defined in the standard it just happens to be defined as *implementation defined*. Which is a big difference compared to *undefined*. -1